# how to apply manual coloring only for one of the groups in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Assume a 2x2 matrix, where there are two rows (each presenting a `technique`) in the input matrix, and each row has two columns. Now  I want to draw a ggplot. In a typical approach for setting the line colors in ggplot, we set the `color` to vary along one dimension (i.e. the columns) and `linetype` to vary along the other dimension (i.e. rows):

```
geom_line(aes(color=m, linetype=techniques))
```

is there a way to force 1 color, i.e. black, for all the  lines belonging to one of the groups? For example, is there a way to do something similar to:

```
### do this first
geom_line(aes(color=m, linetype=techniques))

###and then change the colors for one of the groups, i.e. for techniques1
scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "black"))
```

the above solution changes it for both groups (techniques1 and techniques2).

Comment: Can you show some dummy data? ggplot is going to be easier if you can set the color and linetype by individual columns. Or split original df into two separate dfs plot separate ggplot layers an manual adjust aesthetics there.

Comment: You should be able to force black by not specifying `color` in `aes`

Comment: @Arun how to force black to one group only?

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

```
 df <- mtcars
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=mpg,y=hp)) +geom_line(colour = "black") +geom_line(aes(x=mpg,y=cyl),colour = "black")
```

[image]

or method 2

```
df <- mtcars
df1 <- df[,-2,-3]
df2 <- df[,-4,-5]
ggplot(data=df1,aes(x=mpg,y=hp)) +geom_line(colour = "black")+geom_line(data=df2,aes(x=mpg, y = cyl), colour="black")
```

[image]

I know the y-axes aren't of the same units.. but this was just to show how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a new variable to control the color, e.g.

```
df$newColor <- paste(df$techniques, df$m, sep = "_")
df$newColor[df$techniques == "1"] <- "technique 1"
```

or, if you have more techniques that you want colored, but not named separately:

```
df$newColor <- df$techniques
df$newColor[df$techniques == "1"] <- "technique 1"
```

Then use that `newColor` column as your color variable